# Can I have a function name be an array variable?

Tags: javascript, function

Can I have a JavaScript loop like this?

```
SB = new Array;

for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

   function SB[i]() {

         (code)

   } // end of function

} // end of for loop
```

I know that doesn't work but how can I make something like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make an anonymous function and return it to the variable.

```
var SB = [];
for (i=1;i<6;i++) {
    SB[i] = function() {
        //(code)
    }
}
```

Note that arrays in javascript is 0-indexed.

So you fetch the first item in the array using

```
myArray[0]
```

And the last using

```
myArray[ myArray.length - 1 ]
```

---

So i think you want to loop with  `i=0`:

```
var SB = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    SB[i] = function() {
        //(code)
    }
}
```

....

```
console.log(SB) // [function() {},function() {},function() {},function() {},function() {}]
```

Instead of:

```
[undefined, function() {}, function() {}, function() {}, function() {}, function() {}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var SB=[];
for (i=1;i<6;i++) {
    SB[i] = function () {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can now invoke it this way:

```
SB[1]();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bracket notation:

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 6; i++ ) {

    SB[i] = function() {

    };

}
```

This attaches a function expression to the array at index `i`. You are allowed to call it like this:

```
SB[ 1 ]();
SB[ 2 ]();

// etc..
```